# Programming Video Games for the Evil Genius:Project 10:Radical Racing-The Cars

Tags: java, video

[image]

Iv'e looked all over for answers to this book. And I know anyone else who has tried to read this book feels the same way. It's called "Programming Video Games for The Evil Genius" Is there anyone who has read this book? I'm on project 10:Radical Racing-The Cars. Everything compiles correctly but for some reason my cars are not showing up in the correct spot on the JFrame. They should be showing up under the two white lines. I'm positive the code is exactly the same as in the book, but the book is wrong. I have already tried changing the HEIGHT part of the point of origin but no matter what I do it does not budge. I can't attach an image because I don't have a rep of at least 10 .This is the code that the deals with the placement of the cars.

```
public class TheCars extends JFrame
{
final int WIDTH = 900; int HEIGHT = 650;

double p1Speed = .5, p2Speed = .5;


Rectangle p1 = new Rectangle(WIDTH/9,HEIGHT/2, WIDTH/30,WIDTH/30);


Rectangle p2 = new Rectangle(((WIDTH/9)+((int)((WIDTH/9)*1.5)/2)),(HEIGHT/2)+    
(HEIGHT/10),WIDTH/30,WIDTH/30);
//the constructor
public TheCars()
{
    //the following code creates the JFrame
    super("Radical Racing");
    setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    //start the inner class (which works on it's own because it is a thread)
    Move1 m1 = new Move1();
    Move2 m2 = new Move2();
    m1.start();
    m2.start();

  }
  //this will draw the cars and the racetrack
  public void paint(Graphics g)
 {
     super.paint(g);

  //set the color to blue for p1
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    //now draw the actual player
    g.fill3DRect(p1.x,p1.width,p1.width,p1.height,true);

    //set the color to red for p2
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    //now draw the actual player
      g.fill3DRect(p2.x,p2.width,p2.width,p2.height,true);

}
private class Move1 extends Thread
{
    public void run()
            //This should all be in an infinite loop so that the process repeats.
    {
        while(true)
        {
        //now put in the try block. This will let 
        //the program exit if there is an error
        try
        {
            //first refresh the screen
            repaint();
            //increase speed a bit
            if(p1Speed<=5)
                p1Speed+=.2;
            p1.y-=p1Speed;

            //this delays the refresh rate
            Thread.sleep(75);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //if there is an exception (an error), exit the loop
            break;

        }

        }
    }
}

private class Move2 extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
    //this should all be in an infinite loop so the process repeats
    while(true)
    {
    //now put the code in a "try" block.
        //this will let the program exit if there is an error
        try
        {
            //first refresh the screen
            repaint();
            //increase the speed a bit
                    if(p2Speed<=5)
                        p2Speed+=.2;
                    p2.y-=p2Speed;

                    //this delays the refresh rate
                    Thread.sleep(75);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //if there is an exception (an error), exitthe loop
            break;
        }
    }
    }

 }
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    new TheCars();
}

}
```

Comment: This question may be unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. If you need help, you will have to post more information, enough so that those of us without the book will be able to help you.

Comment: What are the values of HEIGHT and WIDTH?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  The best I can guess now is 'the code is wrong'.

Comment: @web_bod -- clearly, they're the boxes that are later painted in red and blue, respectively.

Comment: I wouldn't say it was clear at all, rectangles are just structures, surely there's more code to actually implement them as red and blue rectangles on the screen.

Comment: I included some more code involving the color and what will eventually constitute as the blocks movement but I think the Rectangle p1 and Rectangle p2 methods are where the problem is

Comment: I've actually read this book and have been stuck on this for a while ... Turns out that the problem (in my case) had something to do with `repaint();`. How did you even get this code to render properly? I tried copying your code to NetBeans (along with a bunch of imports and other minor changes) and all that comes up is an empty JFrames window, I removed the `repaint();` and it rendered, but the cars won't accelerate/move without it.

Comment: I wish I could tell you lol. Unfortunately, this was posted 4 years ago and I don't think I ever really got it working. I even tried contacting the author or publisher of the book, but no luck. I didn't get through the whole book either. I think I got bored after this exercise. So you might be in better shape than I am in this regard.

Comment: @MartinMarino I finally figured all of this out. Remove the `super.paint(g);` line, it causes unnecessary recursion. The two threads will always call the `repaint();` whenever they need to.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're painting those `Rectangle` objects directly onto the screen, we have to assume that the expressions "`HEIGHT/2`" and "`HEIGHT/2 + HEIGHT/10`" are coming out equal, and nonzero but small. That would be the case if HEIGHT is an `int`, and the value is more than 2 and less than 10. Presumably the value would need to be a couple hundred, at least, for those boxes to show up in the middle of the screen. Check the value of `HEIGHT` (just using a `System.out.println()` would be fine) and make sure it's the actual height of the window.

**EDIT**

Now that we see the rest of the code: the second argument to each call to `fill3DRect()` is wrong. It should be the `y` member of the `Rectangle` objects, which is a large, varying number, but you're passing the `width` member, which is a small fixed number. Change both the calls to look like this and you'll be back on track:

```
g.fill3DRect(p1.x, p1.y, p1.width, p1.height, true);
```

Comment: I'm still trying to understand the code myself but I already tried changing the values to numbers in the hundreds. There not moving.

Comment: @MartinMarino -- thanks for showing us more code; I've edited my answer to include the correct solution. Please remember to mark my answer as "accepted."

Comment: WOOOOOW. I can't believe I made that mistake. I don't know if I would have ever caught that. Thanks a lot for the help. I'm pretty sure the code is behaving the way it should now. If I could give you a thumbs up I would but I'm new and need a rep of at least 15.

Comment: I responded to your comment as being helpful. Is that what you mean by marking as accepted?

Comment: @MartinMarino: you click the big check mark to accept an answer. Doing this reflects favorably on you!

Comment: I can't yet. I need a rep of at least 15.